# Lua script error Msg_429

Tags: lua, package

I don't know what to do with this problem I am currently having and desperate as I am not a programmer or have any knowledge on lua script. I hope that you can help me solve this problem.

Here is my problem...
I play a game called Age of Wushu or Wulin (EU version). After I installed the game and updated it, I press the play button and 10 seconds nothing happen then a box title lua script with an error message "Msg_429". After the game loading screen pop up, once the loading bar reach 100% nothing happen just a notification of the game on the bottom right of my screen and nothing appear. Anyone know what is going? I have done the basic such as check for file corruption (which I think there is none) and uninstall/reinstall the game. I have contacted the GM for the US and EU version and none seems to get back to me or I just think they don't care (really horrible service). I have search google for the problem and I don't think anyone have solved the problem. The game file there is a folder called "res" with a lua.package. There is also the updater and updater_ folder both with updater_lua.package and updater_lua.res. I think the problem have to do with the lua.package in the res folder because when I delete that everything works, but the game have another error because the lua.package is gone. Anyone please help!

I forgot to mention I did download Microsoft latest visual studio 2015, framework and have SQL server...none of these work!

Comment: [The similar problem](http://www.ageofwushu.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=25764)

Answer (score 0):

That error message is created by the game's programmers. Its nothing lua specific.
So I'm afraid that without knowing the meaning of that error code even a lua programmer can't help you.

You can try to open some lua-named files in a text editor and see if you find a lua script but I don't think you will find anything.